# Appium Inspector doesn't capture the Windows pop up window

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver, appium-inspector

When using Appium + WinAppDriver to write the automation for configurating some Windows settings, we found the Windows pop up window **doesn't captured by Appium Inspector on Windows 11 machine**.
[image]

It can be captured on Windows 10 machine.

What tried:
We tried find this item with its Name in code, but it cannot be found:

```
SettingsSession.FindElementByName("Windows Media Player Legacy").Click();
```

Expected:
We want the code can run on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 to select one item in the pop up window.
How can we capture it with Appium + WinAppDriver on Windows 11?